# Scrapy error for multiple formrequest

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, python-requests

I am using scrapy to login into a website using FormRequest, but since the site is built in ASP.Net, for pagination, I have to use FormRequest too, the code is running alright but I don't know how to configure it for pagination since I am new to scrapy. When I use return in parse_item(), it works but I want to work it for pagination, when I use yield in parse_item(), I get this error.

```
2016-08-29 20:44:59 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem,  dict or None, got 'list' in <GET   https://recruiter.cwjobs.co.uk/Recruitment/CandidateSearch/CandidateSearchResults.aspx?SalaryRateTypeId=1&SalaryRangeIds=17%2c18%2c19%2c20%2c21%2c22%2c23%2c24%2c25%2c26&LastActivityId=15&Radius=-1&JobTypeProfile=20&LimitSearch=True&CandidateSearchCriteria=vKYIkjLZq5Af6OEmkANngg%3d%3d&scr=1&iasc=0>
```

This is my code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from cwjobs.items import CwjobsItem


class RecruiterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "recruiter"
    allowed_domains = ["recruiter.cwjobs.co.uk"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://recruiter.cwjobs.co.uk/loginReturnUrl=%2fhome%3fRHP%3dnav_bar_SignIn/',)

    def start_requests(self):
        return [FormRequest("https://recruiter.cwjobs.co.uk/login/",formdata={"__EVENTTARGET":"","__EVENTARGUMENT":"","__VIEWSTATE":"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","__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"607E8F97","LoginPanel$txtUsername":"*******","LoginPanel$txtPassword":"*********","LoginPanel$btnSubmit":"Sign in","Register$txtFirstName":"","Register$txtLastName":"","Register$txtCompanyName":"","Register$txtBusinessPhone":"","Register$txtEmailAddress":"","Register$txtPassword":"","Register$txtPasswordConfirm":"","Register$txtCharityNumber":"","txtReminderUsername":""})]

    def parse(self,response):
        print response.xpath("//h1[@class='account-name']/text()").extract()
        return Request("https://recruiter.cwjobs.co.uk/Recruitment/CandidateSearch/CandidateSearchResults.aspx?SalaryRateTypeId=1&SalaryRangeIds=17%2c18%2c19%2c20%2c21%2c22%2c23%2c24%2c25%2c26&LastActivityId=15&Radius=-1&JobTypeProfile=20&LimitSearch=True&CandidateSearchCriteria=vKYIkjLZq5Af6OEmkANngg%3d%3d&scr=1&iasc=0", callback = self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        candsearch = response.xpath("//input[@id='CandidateSearchResults']/@value").extract()[0]
        viewsgenerator = response.xpath("//input[@id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']/@value").extract()[0]
        print viewsgenerator
        newsearch = response.xpath("//input[@id='NewSearchCriteria']/@value").extract()[0]
        searchcriteria = response.xpath("//input[@id='CandidateSearchCriteria']/@value").extract()[0]
        viewstate = response.xpath("//input[@id='__VIEWSTATE']/@value").extract()[0]

        for i in range(1, 3):
            print i
            data = {"__EVENTTARGET":"ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$pgrPager","__EVENTARGUMENT":str(i),"CandidateSearchCriteria":searchcriteria,"NewSearchCriteria":newsearch,"Keywords":"","CandidateSearchResults":candsearch,"__LASTFOCUS":"","__VIEWSTATE":viewstate,"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":viewsgenerator,"ctl00$cphCentralPanel$NewOrExistingSavedSearch":"rdoNewSavedSearch", "ctl00$cphCentralPanel$txtSavedSearchName":"","ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$hdnPopoverLinkClicked":"","ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ucFacetedSearch$txtBoolean":"","ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ucFacetedSearch$hdnIsAutosuggestChosen":"0","ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ucFacetedSearch$searchTypePart$qsSearchType":"rbProfileAndCV", "ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ucFacetedSearch$txtPostcode":"","ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ucFacetedSearch$ddlRadius":"-1", "ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ucFacetedSearch$qsLoc":"rdoPostcode","ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ucFacetedSearch$ddlLastActivity":"15","ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ddlSort":"Relevancy#0", "ctl00$cphCentralPanel$ucSearchResults$ddlPageSize":"50"}
            request = [FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata = data, callback = self.parse_page2)]
            yield request

    def parse_page2(self,response):
        li  = response.xpath("//div[@class = 'row card-row']")
        for l in li:
            item = CwjobsItem()
            firstname = l.xpath(".//a[@class='candidate-lnk']//span[@class='firstName']/text()").extract()
            lastname = l.xpath(".//a[@class='candidate-lnk']//span[@class='lastName']/text()").extract()
            item['name'] = firstname + lastname
            det = l.xpath(".//div[@id='current-expected-row']")
            for d in det:
                currs = d.xpath(".//li[contains(@id, 'CurrentSalary')]/span/text()").extract()
                if currs:
                    item['currs'] = currs[0].strip()
                currjobt = d.xpath(".//li[contains(@id, 'CurrentJobTitle')]/span/text()").extract()
                if currjobt:
                    item['currjobt'] = currjobt[0].strip()
                Experience = d.xpath(".//li[contains(@id, 'Experience')]/span/text()").extract()
                if Experience:
                    item['Experience'] = Experience[0].strip()
                Desiredjob = d.xpath(".//li[contains(@id, 'DesiredJobTitle')]/span/text()").extract()
                if Desiredjob:
                    item['Desiredjob'] = Desiredjob[0].strip()
                Desireds = d.xpath(".//li[contains(@id, 'DesiredSalary')]/span/text()").extract()
                if Desireds:
                    item['Desireds'] = Desireds[0].strip()
                DesiredLoc = d.xpath(".//li[contains(@id, 'DesiredLocations')]/span/text()").extract()
                if DesiredLoc: 
                    item['DesiredLoc'] = DesiredLoc[0].strip()
                phone = l.xpath("//span[@class='action-span hiddendata']/@data-hiddendataurl").extract()
                if phone:
                    item['phonel'] = "https://recruiter.cwjobs.co.uk"+ phone[0]
                cvl = l.xpath("//a[@class='action-link view-cv-icon cv-action-button']/@href").extract()
                if cvl:
                    item['cvl'] = "https://recruiter.cwjobs.co.uk"+ cvl[0]
                emaillink = l.xpath("//a[@class='hiddendata action-link email-candidate']/@data-hiddendataurl").extract()

                if emaillink:
                    emaillink = "https://recruiter.cwjobs.co.uk" + emaillink[0]
                    item['email'] = emaillink
                    # request.meta['item'] = item
                    # yield request
                    # return

                # yield Request(item['cvl'])
                # item['email'] = [response.body] 
                return item
    # def parse_page(self,response):
    #   # item = response.meta['item']
    #   item['email'] = response.body
    #   yield item
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: It most likely means that your FormRequest is missing some data.

Comment: I printed each data, every value was present. But still it displays error

Comment: Hi, Granitos, I edited the question. Can you please review it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return a list when scrapy either expects `scrapy.Item` or `scrapy.Request`.

The culprit lines:

```
request = [FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata = data, callback = self.parse_page2)]
return request
```

To fix this you should either not make request into a list or iterate through it and yield each element.

```
request = FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata = data, callback = self.parse_page2)
return request
# or
requests = [FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata = data, callback = self.parse_page2)]
for r in requests:
    yield r
```

Comment: pagination is not working still. The results are repeated after 50

Comment: @GokuFrieza This answer only answers your question regarding the error. For the pagination issue it's hard to help since it's very specific case and you are probably missing something in formdata, You hardcode all formdata values where in reality you should retrieve them from the page source since very few of them are static values(means they are different on every page). You should use network inspector to reverse engineer the whole process and make sure you are sending the same data asp.net expects.

Comment: The problem is in "FormRequest.from_response(response", if I use raw url, I get pagination(but only in scrapy shell), if I use from_response, I don't get pagination

Comment: @GokuFrieza FormRequest might not capture all of the formdata, so you need to help it out by providing a dictionary of values it might be missing to `formdata` parameter. The issue is that there are no webstandarts for these requests and `from_response` is just taking resources from `form` tag children nodes such as `input` etc. asp.net is a huge offender regarding this and is notorious when it comes to reverse engineering how it works. You usually need to spend a lot of time in network inspector and page source looking if you are missiing anything.